# Using JSONArray with List of beans containing lists

Tags: java, json, javabeans, arrays, org.json

I am trying to convert a List of java beans to a JSON string using json.org's JSONArray object constructor.

Here is the bean:

```
package jackiesdogs.bean;

import java.util.*;

public class UploadLog {
    private String logDescription;
    private List<String> headings;
    private List<List<String>> log;

    public UploadLog(String logDescription, List<String> headings, List<List<String>> log) {
        this.logDescription = logDescription;
        this.headings = headings;
        this.log = log;
    }

    public String getLogDescription() {
        return logDescription;
    }

    public void setLogDescription(String logDescription) {
        this.logDescription = logDescription;
    }

    public List<String> getHeadings() {
        return headings;
    }

    public void setHeadings(List<String> headings) {
        this.headings = headings;
    }

    public List<List<String>> getLog() {
        return log;
    }

    public void setLog(List<List<String>> log) {
        this.log = log;
    }

}
```

And here is the code I am using to convert it to JSON:

```
JSONArray outputJSON = new JSONArray(output,false);
```

I expect to get the following:

```
[{"headings":[{"Vendor Order Id"}],"logDescription":"You are attempting to upload a duplicate order.","log":[{[{"132709B"}]}]}]
```

But instead I get:

```
[{"headings":[{"bytes":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],"empty":false}],"logDescription":"You are attempting to upload a duplicate order.","log":[{}]}]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How is `output` declared?  How is it populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am only familiar with GSON, which is quite reliable.  The following works with GSON.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PlayWithGson2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PlayWithGson pwg = new PlayWithGson();

        List<String> headings = new ArrayList<String>();
        headings.add("Vendor Order Id");

        List<List<String>> log = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        UploadLog ul = new UploadLog("headings", headings, log);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String toJson = gson.toJson(ul);
        System.out.println(toJson);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
{"logDescription":"headings","headings":["Vendor Order Id"],"log":[]}
```